# System.loadLibrary() gives java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkerError: Can't load library

Tags: java, dll

I'm having an issue with loading a simple .dll through java's System.loadLibrary("name.dll");
I have one copy of the dll in C:\libraries\name.dll as well as another copy in the system32 folder.
Note that C:\libraries is NOT in my path environment variable.
For some reason, when I call System.loadLibrary("name.dll"), I am getting:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\libraries\name.dll
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1706)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
```

Even after I removed name.dll from C:\libraries, I am still getting this same error. Is there any reason why System.load is finding the .dll in a place that is not in the path, and why is it still looking in that place even after the file has been removed?

Comment: The dll needs to be in your classpath to be loaded.

Comment: Is it a COM dll? Can it be registered by regsvr32?

Comment: Does `name.dll` have any dependent dlls? Is the Java process running in `C:\libraries`?

Comment: The native libraries have their own search path, configured by the `java.lib.path` system property. But the system path is search as well, so your problem may not be that the system cannot find the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change -Djava.library.path to point to system32 instead of C:\libraries.

Comment: Give it only the library name, and make sure that it's in a path included by -Djava.library.path at the command line